# how to set limit select for CheckBox "react-native-community/checkbox"

Tags: javascript, react-native

hi i want to consider the limit of 2 products when clicking the button of the Checkbox library but i don't know how. Any help is very welcome

my code

```
{product.topping &&
          product.topping.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <View
                key={index}
                style={{
                  marginLeft: spacing.l,
                  marginVertical: spacing.s,
                }}>
                <View key={index} style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                  <CheckBox
                    style={{transform: [{scaleX: 0.8}, {scaleY: 0.8}]}}
                    boxType="square"
                    onTintColor="#FA4A0C"
                    onCheckColor="#fff"
                    onFillColor="#FA4A0C"
                    onAnimationType="bounce"
                    offAnimationType="bounce"
                    animationDuration={0.2}
                  />
                  <Text style={{marginLeft: spacing.s}}>{item}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            );
          })}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the application logic by your own, a library won‘t help you in this case.

Here is a [example](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/toggle-boolean-array) which might help you, you just need to add the logic to prevent more than two active squares.

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';


const ToggleSquareArray = () => {
  const [squareData, setSquareData ] = useState([true, false, false, false, false]);

  const changeSquare = data => {
    //count the current active checkboxes
    //Prevent the execution of setSquareData when two of squareData are true
    setSquareData(data);
    console.log('Data logged');
    console.log(starData);
  };

  return (
    <View>
          <View>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                alignItems: 'center',
                marginTop: 13,
                marginLeft: 19,
                justifyContent: 'space-between',
              }}>
              <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                {squareData.map((item, index) => (
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    key={index}
                    activeOpacity={0.75}
                    onPress={() => {
                      const temp = [...squareData]; // Create a copy of the array you wanna manipulate should do the trick
                      temp.splice(index, 1, !temp[index]);
                      console.log(temp);

                      changeSquare(temp);
                    }}
                    style={{marginHorizontal: 5}}>
                    {item ? (
                      <View style={{height: 50, width: 50, backgroundColor: '#ff0000'}} />
                    ) : (
                      <View style={{height: 50, width: 50, backgroundColor: '#ff00ff'}} />
                    )}
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                ))}
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ToggleSquareArray;
```